# Extensions and Modules and Packages, Oh My!

Tags: python, microsoft, powershell

How do you know if extensions (e.g., [Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)), modules (e.g., [PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)), or packages (e.g., [Python](https://pypi.org/), [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/)) are not malicious? How can you control or monitor that in an environment? Stuff like this get out of hand quickly!

I can only think that strong application whitelisting would control this, or have a security policy for these ***application extras***. (Is there a proper term for that instead of using ***application extras***?)

I'm having trouble finding what Microsoft's stance is for PowerShell modules and the Code Marketplace? How are they making sure that those ***extras*** aren't malicious? How is any business making sure those ***extras*** aren't malicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to vet it yourself by reading the source code before installing and the changes before each update. You can find guides to read each browser's extensions/addons source code here:

- [Chrome](https://www.howtogeek.com/198964/how-to-view-the-source-code-of-a-chrome-extension/)
- [Firefox](https://www.instructables.com/id/Extract-Firefox-Addon-Source-Code/)

As for Visual Studio, you can choose only the extensions which are open source and read their linked repository from their marketplace page.

Regarding security policies, I believe most big companies have a policy for vetting each extension being installed in any service. You'll need an application or infrastructure security team for that.